# How to start an ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, project

In first handling an ASP.NET web project. Is there a step by step procedure to start it? I mean best practices. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/ is one way to start. There are tutorials, video. Probably then go to http://www.asp.net/mvc to learn about MVC

Answer (score 1):

You can find most of the answer on MSDN site
and this would be the answer for you question on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983452.aspx if I understood your phrase "ASP.NET web project" correctly.